# writing a Javascript function outside of scope to fire inside the scope

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js, closures

I use the D3 visualization library for a lot of projects and find myself copying and pasting a lot of boilerplate code for each one. Most projects, for example, start out like this:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 960,
    height = 500;

var svg = d3.select(container_id).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

After this sort of code, every project diverges. Part of the joy of D3 is that you do some specialized, creative coding for each new project.

I want to write a lightweight wrapper for the boilerplate code so that I can skip to the fun part each time, and in so doing I realized I don't quite understand how to properly make a complex, reusable Javascript object. Here's what I started with:

```
var d3mill = function() {
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 960,
        height = 500;

    var svg = d3.select(container_id).append("svg")
       .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    return {
        svg: function() { return svg; },
        call: function(f) { f(); }
    };
};
```

I think I want to be able to do this:

```
 var d3m = d3mill();
 var test = function() {
     console.log(svg);
 };
 d3.call(test);
```

I thought (wishfully) that passing the function through `call()` would cause the function to fire inside the closure of the `d3mill` instance, thus making `svg` be defined.

It would be a huge waste of time to expose every variable in the closure to the outside world in the manner of the `svg()` function above. What's the right way to allow outside functions to operate here?

Comment: Be careful if using `call` as a property name that you don't confuse it with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call. I'm not sure I'd pick that name for this reason.

Comment: Good point, thx. Going to keep it the same here to avoid confusion with existing answers, but duly noted.

Comment: If you're interested, here is a good source on javascript design patterns: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ The Module pattern or the Constructor pattern might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use as a constructor function.

```
var D3Mill = (function() {
    var defaults = {
        margin: { top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
        width: 960,
        height: 500
    };

    function num(i, def) {
        return ("number" === typeof i) ? i : def;
    }

    function D3Mill(container_id, opts) {
        opts = opts || {};
        // Use opts.xxx or default.xxx if no opts provided
        // Expose all values as this.xxx
        var margin = this.margin = (opts.margin || defaults.margin);
        var width  = this.width  = num(opts.width,  defaults.width);
        var height = this.height = num(opts.height, defaults.height);
        this.svg = d3.select(container_id).append("svg")
           .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
           .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
    }

    D3Mill.prototype.perform = function(f) { return f.call(this); };

    return D3Mill;
}());

var d3m = new D3Mill("my_container_id");
// or
var opts = {
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
    margin: { ... }
};
var d3m = new D3Mill("my_container_id", opts);

var test = function() {
    console.log(this.svg, this.margin, this.width, this.height);
};
d3m.perform(test);
```

Comment: I really like this solution (though I learned a ton from @Alnitak !).

Answer (score 1):

If you change you code to this:

```
return {
    svg: function() { return svg; },
    call: function(f) { f.call(this); }
};
```

then it *should* correctly set the context within `test` to be `d3m`.

Within that function you should then be able to access `this.svg()` to get the SVG object, but you will *not* be able to access the "private" lexically scoped variable `svg` directly, i.e.:

```
var d3m = d3mill();
var test = function() {
    console.log(this.svg());   // OK
    console.log(svg);          // not OK - undefined variable
};
d3m.call(test);
```

You could also just pass the `svg` parameter to `f` when it's called:

```
return {
    svg: function() { return svg; },
    call: function(f) { return f.call(this, svg); }  // also added "return", just in case
};
```

with usage:

```
var d3m = d3mill();
var test = function(svg) {
    console.log(svg);          // now OK - it's a parameter
};
d3m.call(test);
```

Comment: Does that get me further than just calling d3m.svg()? The hope was that I not also need a "margin()" function and one for every other useful variable that I need in the boilerplate. But I guess that's the definition of a closure...

Comment: Re: the second suggestion, passing svg as a parameter -- that gives me "undefined", I think because the in-function scope trumps the object scope?

Comment: @ChrisWilson hmm, that's slightly odd.  I don't see any point at which the variable passed in `f.call(this, svg)` is being hidden by the scope of any variable with the same name.

Comment: My mistake, didn't see the (this, svg) in the first part. Yes, that works! Though it doesn't allow me to use any variable in the closure that I want...

Comment: That's essentially the same as saying "function call() { f(svg); } " right?

Comment: @ChrisWilson no, because they're _lexically_ scoped.  re: next comment - no, because that version doesn't set `this` equal to the current D3mill object.

Answer (score 0):

the following will also give you access to the variables you want inside test.

```
var d3mill = function() {
    this.margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 960,
        height = 500;

    this.svg = d3.select(container_id).append("svg")
       .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

};


var d3m = new d3mill();
var test = function() {
  console.log(this.svg);
};
test.call(d3m);
```

Comment: it'll still only give access to the _properties_ of `this`, not any variables declared with `var`.

Comment: ok. I should have included that in the answer. However, I consider that to be a good thing :-)